# Open activity from BottomNavigationView for Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, layout, bottomnavigationview

Title can be wrong, sorry for that.
I use BottomNavigationView. When I click a icon, I want to open a different activity. Some part of my code is below, this code works well.

mainactiyity.java

```
 case R.id.navigation_home:
       Intent Intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SetData.class);
       startActivity(Intent);
       return true;
```

SetData.java

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.set_data);
```

But I want to open new activity under BottomNavigationView. New activity covers the entire screen and I don't see the navigationbar. How can I solve it?

activity.main

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="oww.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

set_data

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorAccent"
tools:context=".SetData">

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need open a Fragment instead of an Activity.

See this blog to know how do it

https://segunfamisa.com/posts/bottom-navigation-view-android

Comment: Thank you, I know fragment but i need to open activity in this project.

Comment: So, the only way is to have a `BottomNavigationView` in all the activities that you want to open from the `BottomNavigationView` and check the option that you want in each one.